# VB.NET How to turn a paragraph of text into one line?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to turn a paragraph of text (grabbed from a textbox) into one continuous line?

I could have the following information:

```
34 MyRoad  
da7 888  
london  
the moon
```

And I want it to read :

```
34 MyRoad da7 888 london the moon
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: spaces added to cause line breaks, and sample data formatted as code

Comment: You can prevent line wrap in stackoverflow by putting two spaces on the end of the line ;)

Comment: ... and you can format your example data as code - which I think makes it more readable? (I have done this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
Dim FullAddress as String = TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbCrLf," ")
```

Comment: This works great for me. This is how I used it for my scenario.    {SystemExceptionLogMessage = SystemException.ToString.Replace(vbCrLf, " ")}

Comment: SystemExceptionLogMessage = SystemException.ToString.Replace(vbCrLf, " ")

Answer (score 2):

You could `Split-Join` the original string:

```
Dim lines = multiLineText.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim oneLineText = String.Join(" ", lines)
```

- [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)
- [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx)

**Edit**: Of course a simple [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)(as Derek has suggested) will do the job also.

```
oneLineText = multiLineText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ")
```